# Invalid Payload Size for Apple Push Notification

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send Apple Push Notifications using C#.  I have my code set up and everything is working great except that the response from Apple is saying Invalid Payload Size.  I have looked through the code and I am not seeing where the invalid Size is coming from.  Below is the code where I generate the payload to send.  I am using Moon APNS to send class library to send.  Any help that anyone can provide on this would be much appreciated.

```
 private static byte[] GeneratePayload(NotifcationPayload payload)
        {
            try
            {
                //Convert Device token to HEX value
                byte[] deviceToken = new byte[payload.DeviceToken.Length /2];
                for (int i= 0; i < deviceToken.Length; i++)
                    deviceToken[i] = byte.Parse(payload.DeviceToken.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                // Command
                memoryStream.WriteByte(1); // Changed command Type

                // Adding ID to Payload
                memoryStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload.PayloadId.ToString()), 0, payload.PayloadId.ToString().Length);

                //Adding Expiration Date to Payload
                int expire = (int) (DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(300) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
                byte[] timeStamp = BitConverter.GetBytes(expire);
                memoryStream.Write(timeStamp, 0 , timeStamp.Length);

                byte[] tokenLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16) 32);
                Array.Reverse(tokenLength);

                //Device Token Length
                memoryStream.Write(tokenLength, 0 ,2);

                //Token
                memoryStream.Write(deviceToken, 0, 32);

                //String length
                string apnMessage = payload.ToJson();
                LogHelper.Info("Payload generated for " + payload.DeviceToken + " : " + apnMessage);

                byte[] apnMessageLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16) apnMessage.Length);
                Array.Reverse(apnMessageLength, 0, 2);
                LogHelper.Info("PushNotification::GeneratePayload : This is the size of the payload " + apnMessageLength);


                //Message Length
                memoryStream.Write(apnMessageLength, 0, 2);

                //Write the Message
                memoryStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apnMessage), 0, apnMessage.Length);
                LogHelper.Info("Writethe message " + memoryStream);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogHelper.Error("Unable to generate payload - " + ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the payload?

Comment: Here is the output from the console window.   Payload generated for cb5b0f120e1b73b64d67dc3e8a12baea74780abe29378ef821498b44d2b928fb : {"aps":{"alert":"test Push Notification","badge":0,"sound":"default.wav"}}

Comment: What do you see in `PushNotification::GeneratePayload : This is the size of the payload`?

Comment: Can you show all the bytes you are writing to the stream (starting in the 1 command and until the payload length)? It's possible you wrote too few bytes before the payload length bytes.

Comment: I was missing a line in the writing of the memorystream and that is what was causing the problem.  I Have corrected the code to show correctly now.